# Can a new iMac be set up to run an earlier version of the Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, osx-mavericks, imac

I am in a situation where I need to get a peripheral Mac device. The Mac OS is only useful to me up to 10.9, which was shipped in the late 2013 models. However, for as much as it will cost to get an old 2013 iMac with the hardware I need, I might as well just buy a brand-new one from Apple.

Considering that, can a new iMac be set up to run OSX 10.9? Or, will I just have to get a 2013 (or earlier) model for it?

Comment: Note that you will need to have 10.9 already in your App Store purchase history to be able to access it, even for an older model - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no, Apple revision-locks new Macs to only run the OS that it shipped with pre-installed, or later.

The OS your Mac came with has device drivers and bug fixes specific to your Mac, and those are carried forward to later OSes, but never back-ported to earlier OSes. There’s almost no value to Apple or the vast majority of customers to make new Macs run old macOS versions.